# show error messages in typo3

Tags: error-log, typo3-6.2.x

I am wondering if there is a way to show concrete error messages instead of just getting "Oops, an error occurred!" with no further clarifications or hints concerning the error . 
I also checked the file "typo3.log" but it's quite empty .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting value of `[SYS][displayErrors]` to `1`

- login into **Install Tool**,
- go to **All configuration**
- Open **$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']** pane
- search for `[SYS][displayErrors]` and set required value

`1` is ok for local dev, and `2` (with `devIPmask` check) for remote dev. For production disable it again.